# Wordpress the_excerpt() adding extra +-* at beginning of content

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In Latest post loop when I try to echo the_excerpt() function it is adding +-* at the binning of the excerpt content. thanks in advance.

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <article class="media  group">
    <?php 
    // get the tag names of the current post.
    $posttags = get_the_tags($post->ID);
    foreach($posttags as $tag){

    ?>  
    <div class="meta meta--line">
    <h4 class="is-basefont is-inline is-forceful"><a href="#" class="is-category  "><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a></h4>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>#disqus_thread" class="comment-count count-comments fa fa-comment" data-disqus-url="#">
    <?php echo $post->comment_count; ?>
    </a>
    </div>
    <?php  }  //end of get psot tags loop. ?>

    <?php  $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) ); ?>

    <div class="media__body">

    <h2 class="size_3"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" sl-processed="1"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <div class="meta">
    <?php echo ' By <a href="#">'.$author_name = get_userdata($post->post_author)->display_name.'</a>';?>
    <?php echo ' On '. get_the_time('j, F Y g:i a ',$post->ID); ?></small>

    </div>
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p> 

    </div>
    </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: You need to show some code...

Comment: this is loop when i use it at another place it is showing ok

Answer (score 0):

We experienced this exact same problem after migrating a client's WordPress install. We traced it to the "Add This" plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/addthis/

It requires account credentials. When the plugin is activate without those credentials, it outputs those 3 characters. Deactivate the plugin, or add the account credentials to make the +-* go away.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution to remove first spacial characters form the_excerpt function
n depends on how much characters you want to remove
$n=3;

```
 <?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), n,200); ?>
```